# Host resolution error while recording in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, resolution, host

I am getting one  error in Jmeter while trying to do some actions in my application. In my company, I am using some XX proxy to connect to the Internet. However, while trying to record using Jmeter , am using localhost with the port as 80. After did basic settings in workbench -- click on start-- navigate to the browser to do some actions. But, when I click on any button in my application. I am getting this error

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server at
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to record the application after changing the port different from 80.